# Creating a movable geometry object

Tags: c#, events, graphics, geometry

Using the `Graphics` class and a panel, I can draw a geometric shape onto a Form. I understood that i cannot apply events to this shape (like click, drag etc.).

How can i create a geometric shape (perhaps using Points) to which I can apply events, for instance to allow the shape to be moved by dragging and dropping?

Comment: why closed for not real question?

Comment: for example, what do you mean by "applied with events" and by "moved separately" ? I just don't get it. And what does PictureBox have to do with all that? All these things you speak about are mostly unrelated..

Comment: "not a real question" - see the frame below the post. one of causes is "too vague/incomplete"

Comment: I think it'd be better if you post another one. this one is closed, i don't know if it can be re-opened easily

Comment: It can be reopened with enough votes, just like it was closed by enough votes (a moderator's vote is worth 5). I have edited it to hopefully encourage others to vote to reopen it.

Comment: I edited the question if you don't understand ask me.

Comment: Answer as comment: If you attach event handlers directly to the Panel on which you are drawing these shapes, you can use them to determine where the user is hovering the mouse, where they clicked, if they're dragging, etc. You can determine if the user is clicking on a vertex of points (perhaps allowing them to change the shape) or within a set of points defining a polygon (perhaps allowing them to move it). You can then make the necessary changes to an array of Points defining that shape based on the user's mouse "gestures", that are then used to redraw the shape on the next window Paint().

Comment: Thanks alot, how can i know which shape was clicked? and may i have some examples of how to change the shape?

Comment: The question was probably closed because you have not shown any effort to solve the problem yourself; you seem to have the basic idea of what you want (to use Points to draw shapes and allow manipulation of those Points) but have shown no code indicating you've at least made an attempt to do what you want. As such this is an "overt request for code" which is discouraged here, and was closed for that reason (it's "incomplete" because you haven't shown us what you've tried).
.

Comment: As a succinct answer to "how can I know which shape was clicked", implement a "point in polygon" test; given a set of points defining a polygon M and a point P which may or may not be inside M, find a point Q guaranteed to be outside the shape you want to test, draw an imaginary line PQ between P and Q, and find how many line segments of M that imaginary line crosses. If that number is odd, P lies within M.

Comment: 1. post an answer that i can upvote\accept. 2. I havn't provided a code because I don't know how to do it, all I managed to do is draw the shapes. I searched StackOverflow and found a way to detect a string click (string is drawn with `Graphics` class) but not a shape. Thanks again.

Comment: I cannot post an answer because the question has been closed. If you do not know how to attach a handler to the Panel and identify where the user has currently positioned their mouse or has clicked, might I suggest you review the events available on System.Windows.Forms.Panel. Of particular interest to you will be the MouseMove (raised whenever the mouse moves to a new position over the Panel), MouseDown (the user presses a button on the mouse), and MouseUp (the user releases a mouse button) events, which you will handle to identify where the mouse cursor is and what is clicked.

Comment: @KeithS - question appears to be open again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach event handlers directly to the Panel on which you are drawing these shapes, you can use them to determine where the user is hovering the mouse, where they clicked, if they're dragging, etc. You can determine if the user is clicking on a vertex of points (perhaps allowing them to change the shape) or within a set of points defining a polygon (perhaps allowing them to move it). You can then make the necessary changes to an array of Points defining that shape based on the user's mouse "gestures", that are then used to redraw the shape on the next window Paint().

As a succinct answer to "how can I know which shape was clicked", implement a "point in polygon" test; given a set of points defining a polygon M and a point P which may or may not be inside M, find a point Q guaranteed to be outside the shape you want to test, draw an imaginary line PQ between P and Q, and count how many line segments of M that PQ crosses. If that number is odd, P lies within M.

Comment: 1. How can i count the line segments of M that PQ crosses? 2. I don't have a array of points for that shape, the shape is drawn and than its points get deleted and all that remains is the drawn shape..

Comment: Then don't delete the points. Keep them around and use them to draw the shape in future calls to the Paint event handler. As for determining whether two line segments cross, that's a math question, and it has been answered many times both here and on Math.SE.